# How to open a local html file from html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to open a local html file from a running html file.In simple words, when I click on a button in my html page it should open another html page which is stored on my computer only. I have tried using `href` but it is not working.I am using `onclick` so when i click on the button it opens a new window but the html is not loaded on the page.I can only use html or Java Script.

Here is what I am doing

```
<html>
     <head>
      <script lang="Java-Script">
       function func()
       {
         var m='<a href="newone.html" target="-blank"></a>';
         document.write(m);
        }
       </script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <input type="Submit" value="click" onclick="func()">
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is `target="_blank"`. What errors do you get?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/1838483

Comment: To access local files you have to use `file://` URL. Your code looks for `newone.html` on the same server as the running html.

Comment: You should avoid `document.write`, see warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). And use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script lang="Java-Script">`. And better add a doctype to avoid quirks mode. And `<title>` element is missing.

Comment: I tried using `file://` but it is still not working.It just makes the whole screen blank.My `newone.html` is in the same folder as the running one.Do I need to provide the whole path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Forget about `document.write`. If you wanted to add a link element to a web page (not needed here), you could try using `document.createElement` and `document.body.appendChild`.
2. If you want to navigate to an URL through Javascript, you can assign to `window.location`.
3. Instead of a button, maybe you can make a normal link in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery lib. It is very easy.
here you go!

http://fiddle.jshell.net/m7zq9/