# How to link to a local/intranet file within HTML?

Tags: html, anchor, local-files

How do I link to a local/intranet file within HTML?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) and many other questions but it's not working for me. Not using Chrome and not using IE 11. Not for PDFs, WAVs or MP3s. Not clicking, not right-clicking/open-in-new-tab/window, not dragging.

Here's the HTML rendering (it's Ruby on Rails on the server).

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpading="0px" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Verbiage</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Talent</th>
      <th>Audio</th>     
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A book</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>
        <a href="file:///C:\Ruby193\doc\bookofruby.pdf">C:\Ruby193\doc\bookofruby.pdf</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="/prompts/12">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/prompts/12/edit">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/prompts/12" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post when I was looking to answer the same question. Thought I'd post the answer that worked for me in case it helps someone else.

Six slashes worked for me where three didn't. I also didn't need a backslash after my directory letter.

```
file://////Z:/filepath/filename.pdf
```