# jqGrid cell contains file path

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.5.2 & jQuery 1.9.1 and reading an XML file as input into a grid.  One cell has a path that points to a file.  That file may be of several different types (.doc, .htm, .pdf, etc.).

In displaying the grid, I need to have that cell be a hyperlink to that file share.  Using the predefined format type of **link**, it does provide a hyperlink to it, but it puts the web server info in front of the link, such as:

```
http://localhost:55555/\\servername\filepath1\filepath2\thisdoc.doc
```

Everything from the `\\` on is retrieved from the XML.  How do you make the contents of the cell a hyperlink, but suppress the website info?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom formatter for it, like this one:

```
var urlFormatter = function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="' + cellValue + '">' + cellValue + '</a>';
};
```

This way the result should be:

```
<a href="servername\filepath1\filepath2\thisdoc.doc">
    servername\filepath1\filepath2\thisdoc.doc
</a>
```

**Update:**

I did not realize it was a filesystem URL. In that case modify it like this:

```
var urlFormatter = function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="file:///' + cellValue + '">' + cellValue + '</a>';
};
```

Which yields:

```
<a href="file:///servername\filepath1\filepath2\thisdoc.doc">
    servername\filepath1\filepath2\thisdoc.doc
</a>
```

This should work. The reason because it did not work previously was that the browser interpreted the link as a *relative link*, but you wanted a *absolute link* to a part of the filesystem.

Comment: I have that function now in the formatter of the colModel.  The cellvalue is correct, but if you mouseover the link, it still has the http://localhost/55555/ before the file path & returns a 404 Not Found error if you right click & open in a new tab.

Comment: Wait, servername is actually a domain?

Comment: It is a file share, where those various documents (pdf, htm, doc, etc) are located.  In the grid it looks right.  I put a console.log statement to dump the cellvalue out & it looks right also.  But, when you mouseover the link, it's got the "http://localhost:55555/" before the filepath (\\servername\filepath1\filepath2.....).

Comment: I made the change, but had to put one more slash (/) in the file:  portion of the URL.  I can copy the link & paste it in a new window and it will open, but can't right-click on the link (or click on it) to make it open.

Comment: Well, this is the best you can get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page