# Bookmark local HTML file located at %UserProfile%\Desktop\ in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a tiny HTML file with a favicon and a redirect redirect to differentiate a number of URLs which have no custom favicons, on different computers, which I would like to bookmark on Chrome. Since the absolute initial path differs on all computers, I was hoping to use `%UserProfile%\Desktop\` as the path to my file, which would work on all computers, but I don't know whether and how I can enter this kind of path in a URL in Chrome?

Running either Windows 7 or Windows 8 on those computers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you *cannot bookmark dynamic URLs*. What you **can** do is compressing your HTML page into a data URL which can be used as a bookmark:

```
data:text/html;utf-8,<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Title</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico"></head><body><script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace('http://example.com/') },1);</script></body>
```

This is just the following HTML without new lines and `data:text/html;utf-8,` at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- Page title, can be omitted -->
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Link to the favicon in href -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            // URL to redirect to in quotes
            window.location.replace('http://example.com/')
        },1);
    </script>
</body>
```

I just tested this and it seems to display the correct favicon if you provide the path to it. To add it to your bookmarks, right-click the bookmark bar and select `Add page...` then enter the data URL for the location.

If you need to use local favicons, then you can convert your `.ico` to a data URL as well. Here's one tool of many that I found through Google: http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/
A simple search for [`ico to data url`](http://google.com/search?q=ico+to+data+url) should give you relevant results.

You'll get a nice long URL that you can use in place of `http://example.com/favicon.ico` and it'll still be contained within the bookmark.

Comment: thanks DJDavid98. That would work, yet I want to open the URL specifically from Chrome's favicon bar. In fact what I am doing is having a tiny HTML + favicon + redirect to differentiate a number of URLs which show blank favicons. Might be simpler to install a Chrome add-on to manage favicon, but those pile up and slow down my machines so I tend to find other solutions if simple enough. But from your first sentence I may need to switch to such favicon managers.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that extensions cannot access environment variables either. See my edit for a different solution.

Comment: in your example though the favicon used is that of example.com. I am trying to fix for those sites which do not have favicons. This is why I am creating local favicons for those sites and need to access them locally... By the way brilliant learning that I can put the HTML code directly in the URL, will definitely do that if I find a way to find the location of the favicon.

Comment: thanks a million DJDavid98. Works great! :-)  Now I just reuse the same long data:text line with the favicon replaced by a data:image for any favicon bookmark I want to fix and this is fully transportable since embedded in the bookmark URL. And eats up no resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a bookmark of your file location like the following:

```
file:///C:/Users/Account-Name/Desktop/filename.html
```