# Launch local PowerShell script from link in local browser session

Tags: powershell, browser, web, hyperlink, execution

My boss has asked me to look into launching a PowerShell script I've written (which is to be deployed to all users desktops) when the user clicks on a link in their web browser (and not by the clicking on a desktop icon as I've proposed). I did not think this was possible for security reasons and can't understand how this can be done. Does anyone know if this is possible ? i.e. a web link can somehow trigger the running of a PowerShell script held locally on the user's machine? Seems dangerous to me but he says it can be done !!!

Comment: I think this is pertinent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/3829407

Comment: So this is saying it can't and shouldn't be done, thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't automatically run a linked script and will require the user to download and then run it.

The way to accomplish the goal of running a script when they click on something, though, would be to do it with server-side code that launches the script remotely or creates a scheduled task on the user's system.  However, this may not work if the user needs to see the command window or interact with the script.