# Hyperlinking a page to a local page (in files) HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

Im trying to set up a hyperlink from my current page to another page via my files, however it doesn't work...
My code:

```html
<ahref="file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6weeksproject/Index/Languages.html"><input type="image" id="Languages" position:absolute style="height:px; width:px;" src="./CSImages/About.PNG">
  
  <!-- Thats in context, the HREF is following-->
  
  <ahref="file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6weeksproject/Index/Languages.html">
```

Once i click the hyperlink it comes up with an error that repeats the directory:

file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6%20weeks%20project/file///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6%20weeks%20project/Index/Languages.html

How can i fix this?

Comment: There should be a space between the <a and the href attribute. You should probably close the a element as well with a </a>

Comment: Thank you for trying to correct this problem, and i have tried all of your suggestions but it is refusing to work. Also i did add a </a> tag i just missed it off this snippet by accident, sorry... The input is because it is a button, and works fine with the input. Any more suggestions and i will be grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the  tag in conjunction with the `href` attribute work as follows `<a href="path/to/file.html">`. Noticed the difference (space)?

Secondly, if the file is in the same folder, all you need to do is reference the file that you want to link starting from that path and upwards.

You were on the right track, your href would become: {}

Consider naming files with lowercase letters only. Its not necessary, but a well accepted practice!

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6weeksproject/Index/Languages.html">
    <input type="image" id="Languages" position:absolute style="height:px; width:px;" src="./CSImages/About.PNG">
</a>
```

As mentioned in comments, you should put a space between `a` and `href`. Additionally, you should close the `a` tag.

Why are you using an `input` element for showing an image? Maybe you are better off with an actual image tag:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6weeksproject/Index/Languages.html">
    <img id="Languages" style="position:absolute; height:[insert missing value]px; width:[insert missing value]px;" src="./CSImages/About.PNG">
</a>
```

You may also have a look at this SO question for more reference on links to local files: [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` must have a space between the `a` and `href`: `<a href="">`

When you use the `href` attribute, the path will be based on which file you put the `<a>` in, e.g. if you put the `<a>` in the `index.html`, and you want to reference to `languages.html`, first make sure that the `languages.html` is in the same folder as `index.html` (easier) and then just reference to it with:

```
<a href="languages.html">
```

Also, why are you using an `input` tag? Just use an `img` tag. I'll fix your code:

```
<a href="languages.html">
    <img id="Languages" style="position: absolute; height:_px; width:_px;" src="CSImages/About.PNG">
</a>
```

This only works if the folder CSImages is in the same directory as `index.html` If not, just change the path accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add the space in the `a href`, put the image in an `img` tag, and don't include `height` and `width` unless you are going to include a value. Also `position:absolute` has to go in a `style` tag. Finally, close your `a` tag.

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/6weeksproject/Index/Languages.html">
  <img src="./CSImages/About.PNG" style="position:absolute">
</a>
```