# Error "Not allowed to load local resource: file://sharedpath"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The below code is not working when running on server(nodejs) in chrome

```
<span><a href="file://sharedpath" target="_blank">Open folder.</a></span>
```

I am getting the following error message in the developer tool:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file://sharedpath

But when opening the same path(`file://sharedpath`) in the browser(new tab), I am able to see the folder structure of that path.
The same is working fine in IE.
Is this a problem with Chrome? Or is this a problem when running on the server?
Can anyone suggest something on this issue?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: But IE is allowing the same thing. Can I know the reason?

Comment: most browsers don't allow ajax in `file://` protocol for security reasons. Install a local web server

Comment: How did you end up fixing this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your host is fully qualified: 
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Try adding an additional slash: `file:///sharedpath`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/2567455)

Specifically:

> Some browsers, like modern versions of Chrome, will even refuse to cross from the http protocol to the file protocol, so you'd better make sure you open this locally using the file protocol if you want to do this stuff at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your whole context here is, but I used the web server extension for chrome for something similar when testing a local-build of something I'd eventually deploy (but wasn't ready to yet), and it worked great.

Just go to the extension url: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Add the extension, enable it, and point it to the folder that contains the local file that you're having trouble with, and it should work correctly.

Hope that helps!