# Embedding PDF Files in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, embed

I have a page that contains **PDF File** in it. Luckily, it works in IE. But when I run it in **chrome**, it gives me this error : [image]

I googled it and it seems like chrome isn't already allowing us to view PDF's now.
Here is the code for embedding PFD :

```
<div id="pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <iframe src="C:\Users\jmanaban\Downloads\Programming Handbook.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

So the question is, is there still a way or alternatives to embed PDF files in chrome without using any extensions or plugins just like IE? How am I gonna do it? Thanks in advance.

I still didn't this one appear

```
<p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
```

so I think there's still hope.

Comment: See this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509068/error-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-sharedpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the `src` as relative path. Put both `Programming Handbook.pdf` and the HTML file in same folder and change src to:

```
src="Programming Handbook.pdf"
```

Comment: yes. gladly it worked. do you know the reason why it didn't show up when I   im not using a relative path?

Comment: Using local path to files on your computer is not allowed as it'll allow web pages to access any file on your computer

Comment: You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS