# Download msv file in js

Tags: javascript

We try to download **msv** file in js.
Our code:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
                                   link.download = 'SampleReport.msv';
                                   link.href = "C:/Mcf/16-02-2016.msv";
                                   link.click();
```

But it doesn't work.What do we do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `link.href = "C:/Mcf/16-02-2016.msv";` - Javascript in a browser cannot access something on a client's PC. Your href value needs to be something addressable on the web.

Comment: @ neilsimp1 thank u very match! U help as so match!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)