# Yii2 html link to open document on external filesystem

Tags: html, hyperlink, filesystems, yii2, external

I want in Yii2 a simple

**[a href="C:/Vo/AGO/2015.pdf">2015 [/a>** ([ must be a <)

on one of my forms.
I don't want to upload the file, because the pdf (help) file is updated by an external organisation (instead of C: the pad is a server, but for test reasons I use C:), and I have to display a lot of files managed by that organisation.

So I use:

**Html::a("2015", "C:/Vo/Ago/2015.pdf")**

When I run the application and I inspect via show source I see

**[a href="C:/Vo/Ago/2015.pdf">2015[/a>**

But if I click the link on my form, nothing happens!
(When I do the same thing in a simple html document - not yii2 - the pdf opens)

If I copy right-click and copy the link I get:
**file:///C:/Vo/Ago/2015.pdf**

So, what am I missing?
Yes I'am new in Yii2 and I searched a lot on internet to find a solution.

If this is already asked, excuse me, a reference to the solution would then be welcome...

Thanks,

Chris G.M. Logghe

Comment: Even if your code is working on your machine, it will not work on server, because you are trying to access the file locally.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to link "local" file on browser.

> Some browsers, like modern versions of Chrome, will even refuse to
>   cross from the http protocol to the file protocol, so you'd better
>   make sure you open this locally using the file protocol if you want to
>   do this stuff at all.

[See here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page/18246357#18246357)

The best option for you is to create action on controller and perform download file there.

In your view:

```
$data = 'C:/data/mydata.log';
echo Html::a('Download', ['sample-download', 'filename' => $data], ['target' => '_blank']);
```

In your controller:

```
public function actionSampleDownload($filename)
{
    ob_clean();
    \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($filename)->send();
}
```

Of course, you **must** limit to specific directory rather than user give full access to filename.