# Why do I get a wrong link when click?

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Speaking English</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\hss\Desktop\essay\css\speaking.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Supercharging</h1>
        <div class="table">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/hss/Desktop/essay/about/index.html"/>Home</li>
                <li><a href=""/>About Us</li>
                <li><a href=""/>Contact</li>
                <li><a href=""/>Career</li>
                <li><a href="C:\Users\hss\Desktop\essay\about\feedback.html"/>Make Suggestion/Feedback</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  

        <p>
        <article>

            <img src="C:\Users\hss\Desktop\essay\img\alec.PNG" alt="English Alec"/>

        </article>

        </p>

</body>
</html>
```

/*  I do not know why when I click the picture in the article, the Make Suggestion link in the list is called. 
    Please help.
    thanks */

Comment: try usin file:/// . read more here on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page/18246357).

Answer (score 2):

You Just Made a mistake in Closing The Achor Tag.

```
        <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/hss/Desktop/essay/about/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Career</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:\Users\hss\Desktop\essay\about\feedback.html">Make Suggestion/Feedback</a></li>
```

You Have to Close The anchor Tag as `</a>`