# js file not loading js console say's "Not allowed to load local resource"

Tags: javascript, html

The *JavaScript* code below is not loading, in the *JavaScript console* it says,

> "Not allowed to load local resource:"

**Javascript:**

```
    (function () { 
        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
        script.setAttribute('src','file:///home/chronos/u-1dd073c6b7b8430c0010c7429b07db331325c324/Downloads/Core/tube.js'); 
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        }()
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This stuff is mostly pasted from other questions but perhaps you will find it useful:**

Check if your host is fully qualified [in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

You can also read a guide [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page/18246357#18246357)

Some browsers, like modern versions of Chrome, will even refuse to cross from the http protocol to the file protocol. Chrome and Safari seem to use a more strict implementation of sandboxing (for security reasons) than the other two.

Finally, you shouldn't load javascript files off a local filesystem. You need to have it hosted with your app and load it off the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a python server using

> python3 -m http.server 8086

and replace the

> file:///<PATH_TO_FILE>

with `https://localhost:8086/<RELATIVE_PATH_TO_FILE>`