# How to use File:// with a folder which is not in the Repository

Tags: trac

I am new to Trac so be patient with me.
I installed Trac with the Bitnami installer in a Windows8.1 Virtual Machine on my Server. 
Now to my Problem, I want to create "downloadable" links inside my wiki pages.
To create the link i use the [File://] command.
I have the correct link (in this case: [file:///Z:/Software/NotepadPlusPlus.exe]).
In my wikipage I have this: [file:///Z:/Software/NotepadPlusPlus.exe NotepadPlusPlus] and in the Internet Explorer it works perfectly fine but not on Firefox and Google Chrome.
When i copy the Link and Enter it in the those browser, it works. But when I click on the link inside trac, nothing happens.

I hope you can help me or give me a tipp.

Comment: You are probably running into an issue with the browser refusing the `file://` protocol for security reasons. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/121694). Could you describe in detail what you are trying to do? There is probably a better solution that creating links with the `file` protocol.

Comment: My Trac is hostet on a Virtual Machine and I want to create "download-links" to a server in my domain.
We have a wikipage called "Software". There are wiki pages for all Software that is necessary in the company and for some installation/configuration guides. Basicly If I need Notepad++, I want to go to the wiki page and click on the link to "download" it from the local server. 
The Local Server is not on the Virtual machine. Is is hostet on a different machine, but it is connected to Windows Drive (Z in this case) on all company machines.

Comment: And the normal "file:///" works with all browser, Only the click on link does not

Comment: You should put the files in a location that is served by your web server and use project-relative URLs and the HTTP protocol rather than the `file` protocol. Are you running [TracStandalone](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone), or a web server such as Apache?

Comment: I installed the Bitnami Version of Trac. There is an Apache Webserver. The problem is, that I can't copy all files we need in the Virtual Machine where trac is hosted. That's why i tried it with File

Answer (score 0):

You should put the files in a location that is served by your web server and use project-relative URLs and the HTTP protocol rather than the `file` protocol. The link rendering is just too browser-specific.

(barely copy-pasted this from comment by user rjollos, to formally get this question out of unanswered state)