# How Can I put a link if I have three files?

Tags: html

I have the following website:

http://luscoefusco13.es

I would like to know how to put a link that redirects to the main page, if I have three files, index.html, main.html and top.html?. It has frames, that is the difference between the question asked in the example of similar case.

Comment: Did you actually tried to google it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

Comment: Bálint it is a different case, it works with frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply `/`, as in `<a href="/">Link text</a>` - this will always link to the root of your website, regardless of the visitor's current location on your site, or the site's domain name.

Comment: Hi Dai, I have tried and the website blocked the navigation menu.

Comment: Referring to the asked question of Rolin, Can you help me?.

Answer (score 0):

With target="framename"

```
<ul> 
  <li><a href="example.html" target="top">A frame</a></li>
  <li><a href="example.html" target="main">B frame</a></li>
```

This is the site where 
I have it from:

http://www.tagindex.net/html/frame/a_target.html

Comment: Hi Rolin, I used taget="self" and it runs but when I load the website it opens in a new window. How Can I correct this?. <frame src="top.html" name="top" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="top" title="top" />
  <frame src="main.html" name="main" id="main" title="main" />, that is the code at index.html.

Comment: I used "blank" too and happened the same.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro Hi you need the name of frame name to the name of the target. so you target="self" than you need the <frame sc="top.html" name="self" .....>

Comment: I undesrtood, however it opens a new window, How Can I solve that?.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro can you share your code of your page?

Comment: This is the index.html 

<frameset rows="30,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="top.html" name="top" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="top" title="top" />
  <frame src="main.html" name="main" id="main" title="main" />
</frameset>
<noframes><body>
</body>
</noframes></html>

Comment: This is the top.html part 1 <body>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="index.html" target="top"><b><font size="2">Brais Remeseiro</font></b></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:luscoefusco13@gmail.com">luscoefusco13@gmail.com</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="01.html" target="main">Ars Moriendi</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="02.html" target="main">Cds, LPs and tapes</a>

Comment: This is the top.html part 2 &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="03.html" target="main">Flyers</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="04.html" target="main">Pages Of Death & Sex</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="05.html" target="main">Posters</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="06.html" target="main">Tributes</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/100863655@N07/" target="_blank"><img src="cloud.png" alt="See my pictures in Flickr!" title="See my pictures in Flickr!" width="23" align="top" /></a> 
</body>

Comment: This is main.html <body>
<table width="*" height="1000" border="0" cellspacing="40">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top"><img src="portrait.jpg" alt="Brais Remeseiro" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro and what if you delete your id="top" everywhere

Comment: Does not run, just stay in the front cover of the web and I have not access to the links.

Comment: The problem is to avoid a new window when I press the Brais Remeseiro. If you can solve that trouble the website works ok.

Comment: Roli, I do not know how now it is working but I solved it with _parent. Yeah, parent with _ before.