# Download file from local path / server path using html tag <a> (newbie)

Tags: html

I am trying to download a file on image click using following code -

```html
<a href="file:///D:\dir\a.pdf" target="_self" download>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" id="download">     </i>
</a>
```

If I add any html url, it's working fine but here it dosen't do anything. Please help

**[EDIT]**

I have even tried -

```html
<a href="file:///D:/dir/a.pdf" target="_self" download>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" id="download">     </i>
    </a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page

Comment: @soorapadman I did follow these steps but its not working for me. If I give any url, it works.

Comment: Ok . let me check then

Answer (score 0):

Using `file:///...` will only work if your HTML page is also local (opened via `file:///` also). If that is not the case look at: http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-file-url.html

Comment: Ok. Open your target file in the browser. Copy the path from the adress bar and paste it instead of the path you are using now. Is there a difference?

Comment: One more thing: This will only work if your HTML page is also local (opened via file:/// also).

Comment: html page is running through a mvc project with a different path. So its searching the file from path - localhost:45678/Admin/D:/dir/a.pdf.... and not in D:/dir/a.pdf... Can you suggest anything for this.

Comment: I'll add a link to my answer for this case.

Comment: best approach would be serve the file you want to download via a php or any other server side language you use. This can minimize your security risks and give you full control over what needs to be done. [This link](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/) has a good tutorial on that.

Comment: Yes. If he can access the files from his local server this is the preferred way.