# how to instantiate DomSanitizationService

Tags: angular

I need to remove unsafe from my url: unsafe:blob:http://localhost:1234/example, Below is what I did.

Script:

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

class example{
  public DomSanitizer: DomSanitizationService;
  public url;

  constructor() {
    this.url = 'www.example.com';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href={{DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(url)}}>
```

However, it gives me error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bypassSecurityTrustHtml' of undefined. I checked DomSanitizationService in @angular/platform-browser, it is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. What is the right way to call? I saw a lot of answer like this ([How to avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to link by Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular2)), the DomSanitizationService is passed from constructor but I don't understand when instantiated the class, what should be passed in. Besides, I don't want to change the contract of constructor. I would like to know what is the right way to achieve my goal. I am using angular2.

**Update**:
Now I am able to make it work by injecting DomSanitizationService through constructor, however, in my test,
I need to instantiate my component and what should be passed in for DomSanitizationService?

Comment: i think this question is already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222357/angular-6-sanitize-local-drive-url/53224277#53224277

Comment: check the above thread  , it has the answer you are seeking

Answer (score 1):

Need to inject the `DomSanitizer` through constructor

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

class example{ 
  public url;

   constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {

      this.url = 'www.example.com';
   }

   transform() { 
      return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.url);
   }

}

<a href={{transform()}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `DomSanitizer` service in your component

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';


export class Example {
    htmlData:SafeHtml
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
       this.url = 'www.example.com';
    }

    renderTab() {
       let temp=`<a href="${this.url}">`
                this.htmlData=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(temp);
            }

        }
    }
```

}

Use this inside html like

```
<span [innerHTml]="htmlData"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle it would be to create a sanitizer Pipe. Later on instead of making copy of your functionality you would be adding only something like `data| sanitize:'html'`.

Angular docs -> https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Pipe creation example [here](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b).