# Angular Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/

Tags: angular, image, sanitize

I am using Angular 7 and am trying to sanitize images from the local system in order to be displayed in the chrome browser, but for each method I am getting the error: 
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/poze/poxulet/poza_profil.jpg [http://localhost:4200/].

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

---

This is the first method that I tried:

In template .html

```
<img mat-card-image [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(service.image)"/>
```

In component class .ts:

```
  export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  service.image = "C:/poze/poxulet/poza_profil.jpg";
  }
```

---

This is the second method:

In template .html

```
 <img mat-card-image [src]="getSanitizeUrl(service.image)"/>
```

In component class .ts

```
 export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 public getSanitizeUrl(url : string): SafeUrl {
   return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
 }

  ngOnInit() {
  service.image = "C:/poze/poxulet/poza_profil.jpg"; }
```

Comment: You can find the answer for the same here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222357/angular-6-sanitize-local-drive-url/53224277#53224277

Comment: Also you need to use the file:/// protocol (yes, that's three slashes) if you want to link to local files. But  Chrome won't download local files using the file:/// protocol anyway (giving you a Not allowed to load local resource error) . You may check following article :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page

Answer (score 0):

file:/// is added by the server itself so it didn't find the image.
Try to store image in asset folder and give url of that path. Then You are good to go.