# Remove Html Encode Character From Link In Angular8

Tags: angular

How can I remove these encoding in angular? Or replace them when routing...

[image]

This is simple html link

> /pages/usersadmin

but when it renders it encoded **"/"** into **"/%2F%2F"**

Comment: are you looking for  safe url ,  here is the  answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222357/angular-6-sanitize-local-drive-url/53224277#53224277

Comment: Can you show the html file and the related component class. Usually anchor tags will not be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you show on screen is indeed encoded with **encodeURIComponent** so if you use the opposite **decodeURIComponent** on that string you will get the url.

```
link: any = decodeURIComponent('http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3F%3Dtest');
// will be decoded as http://localhost?=test
```