# Sanitize url in an object rather than single url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, sanitization

I have an object having `success`, `summary` and `detail` elements used for displaying message in PrimeNG message (`p-messages`) after record is created. After record is created I call `displayMessage` method in order to set `msg` variable

***form.ts:***

```
...
this.displayMessage(data);
```

***baseForm.ts:***

```
displayMessage(data: string) {
    var success = data["success"];
    var summary = data["summary"];        
    var detail = data["detail"]; // <a href="http:/.... ">name</a>
    this.msg.push({ success: success, summary: summary, detail: detail });
}
```

and then display message as shown below in `html`:

```
<p-messages [value]="msg"></p-messages>
```

However, the hyperlink tag “<a” is changed to “<a” and I think I need to sanitize the url by using something as explained on [Angular 6 sanitize local drive url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222357/angular-6-sanitize-local-drive-url). Although I tried to use that method, I did not succeed because I need to sanitize the url in the detail variable and the related method is on the base class. So, how can I make the url display correctly? And what changes should be made in the given example?

Comment: Inside data['detail'] do you only have the url string (`http://....` ) or the html a element (`<a href="http:/.... ">name</a>`) ?

Comment: @gbalduzzi Detail has hyperlink like `<a href="http:/.... ">name</a>`.

Comment: On the other hand, I debugged hyperlink until it come to html and the hyperlink sees to be ok. But in the html page, it is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must tell primeNG not to escape the detail:

```
<p-messages [value]="msg" [escape]="false"></p-messages>
```

Comment: **You rock!..** Where have you been? I have look at many pages regarding to the problem and have not seen any solution even if more difficult one comparing to your solution :) It is very simple and elegant, voted++ ;)

Comment: I just googled for the [official documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/messages)

Comment: If the answer is correct you should mark it as accepted, unless you want to wait for more answers

Comment: Of course will mark it answer, but I have to wait some minutes as SO does not let me mark as answer. Now it is OK.

Comment: What is escape meaning in here? Escape from some characters?

Comment: If you enable escaping, HTML custom symbols (such as `<`, `>`) are escaped, i.e. trasformed in a way that browsers does not treat them as HTML symbols but at a normal text. Without escaping, it would be impossibile to print `<` in a page. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references