# Adding link to a local file on html

Tags: html

I have a file in linux with some path x/y/z 
I have to add a link on the webpage which can open this file in windows Chrome/firefox

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: I have tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page  . But it does not open the file in windows browser since my file is in linux

Comment: This is probably a longshot, but try linking with `href="~/"` where "~" can be considered the  "root" of your webpage directory.