# How to link local files through html

Tags: html, pdf, server, hyperlink

I need to link from local server to multiple computers. It works if I save the page locally on each machine but does not when launched from the web server.

I've looked around and read that Chrome or other broswers is blocking access by default and i get the about:blank#blocked error

the link I am using is

a href="file://server/fileshare/Public/ProductionPDF/M511%20&%20M115IND/E511-11.pdf

file://server/fileshare/Public/ProductionPDF/M511%20&%20M115IND/E511-11.pdf

tried with IE, chrome, firefox and they do nothing. Chrome says about:blank#blocked error - IS there a workaround for this? I've searched a lot of other threads and just cant seem to find one with correct info.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the reason: you need to use three lashes protocol for URI scheme. 
For example :

```
<a href="file:///C:\Documents\doc.pdf">Link</a>
```

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/11794267

Comment: OK, so using file://server/fileshare/Public/ProductionPDF/M511%20&%20M115IND/E511-03-M.pdf as my link I am able to get it to open in Chrome ONLY by "copy link address" and then pasting it into the browser and hitting enter. Otherwise I get the "about:blank#blocked" error.  In firefox It works when I click "open in new tab" but then also have to press enter. Can this be bypassed?

Comment: Em, interesting. Did you use three lashes?

Comment: @paradox3ed Did you ever get this to work? I have the same issue as you. The file links work when copy & pasted into a new tab manually, but not if clicked, open link in new tab, etc.