# Make parts of an image open another file

Tags: image, hyperlink

Hi I have an image and I want to make it so that clicking on a certain area in the image opens another file stored locally on my computer. I can use whatever image file is appropriate but this is my first time facing a problem like this so I have no idea how to go about it.

Also this is my first question here I hope this is the right place to ask.

Comment: you're looking for html maps, I guess: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: @B. Go But it looks like the function opens a link on click but I want it to open another image... sorry I've never used this before

Comment: I think it's the same as opening urls, with fil://, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page