# Download a local file using `<a href= "file://link/to/my/file" ` not working on chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, href, local-files

The link [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) doesn't help me, since the problems are not the same

I have the folowwing html code

`<a href = "file://link/to/my/local/file/my file.xltx" target="_blank"> Download my file </a>`

written inside `index.php` file

In IE, it works fine, but when coming to Chrome, it doesn't work

I want to force Chrome (or any other browser) to download the file using `php` script only, whithout using chrome extension or configuration

Can any one help me ? Thanks in advance

**Remarks**

- I tried curl method, but the problem is that the `php` script is server side, so the target location will be relative to server not to client
- When I copy paste `file://link/to/my/local/file/my file.xltx` the the chrome adress bar, it works fine

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to the space in the link. Try and rename the file to not have a space and see if that works.

Comment: From the duplicate — "You cannot cross from http(s) to the file protocol" — it only works in IE because IE is ancient, insecure junk.

Comment: @Zeth          In IE it works, when I copy paste `file://link/to/my/local/file/my file.xltx``to chrome adress bar, it works fine
Thanks for the remark, I will update the question

Comment: @Quentin       Is there any alternative way to access local file with secure methods (php only) ? thanks in advance

Comment: PHP on the server cannot access the client's filesystem at all. It would be a major security issue if every website you visit could go poking around your hard disk.