# `file:///` prefixed local file links don't get rendered as links in VS Code Markdown Preview on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm trying to link to a local `bat` file using Markdown and the `file:///` [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/1883050) in `VS Code 1.83.1` on `Windows 11` such that when I click on the link to the `bat` file, the `bat` file runs (i.e. the code inside it gets executed).

---

**NPP**

I am able to do it successfully on Notepad++ (NPP).

In NPP, I can do this:

[image]

Then, using the MarkdownViewer++ plugin, I get this in the preview window:

[image]

If I click on the blue "VLC", the linked `bat` runs (the code inside is executed).

**Note:** I haven't illustrated it here, but the above also works in the markdown editor [**Typora**](https://typora.io/).

---

**VS Code**

When I try the same on VS Code with the "Markdown All In One" VS Code extension installed (and in a file with a `.md` file extension in the filename):

[image]

I get this in the Markdown preview window:

[image]

I don't get a clickable "VLC" link.

(**Note:** I've also tried it in VS Code with forward slashes `/` in the full path name, but get a similar result.)

Is there any way to get a clickable link that just says "VLC"? Just like I get in NPP?

Comment: `file://` URLs are supposed to use forward slashes, not backslashes, but that's not the root of your problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for mentioning that. I tried the whole path in VSCode with forward slashes and that didn't work either. Have updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Isn't it `file://` with two slashes? The third one is probably the first character of the path.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I know it looks very suspect, but in Windows it's three forward slashes `file:///`, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/1883050

Answer (score 1):

`file://` links aren't supported in the builtin Markdown Preview. See [markdown file:/// links don't render in Preview
#182870](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182870), which was closed due to not receiving enough community support in the allotted time window. You can try raising it again.

Also, If you're using Windows paths, I'm pretty sure you should be writing something like `file://C:` instead of `file:///C:`. Though due to `file://` not being supported in the Markdown Preview right now, that's a secondary problem. Note though that you can at least get a clickable link in the *editor* (not the Markdown Preview) to `C:\foo\bar\baz.txt` by using a form like `file:///foo/bar/baz.txt`. Also related to Windows absolute paths in the editor for Markdown files, see [Full Windows file path in markdown link does not work #164650](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182870).

Comment: Thanks. Regarding, `you can at least get a clickable link in the *editor* (not the Markdown Preview)`. Yes, this does happen, except, when I click it, instead of running the target `.bat` file, it opens the target in VSCode.

Comment: If you could please clarify, there's something I didn't understand in your text. You wrote "I'm pretty sure you should be writing something like `file://C:` instead of `file:///C:`" but then later you used  the triple-slash structure in `file:///foo/bar/baz.txt`. So, according to you, is the triple-slash structure correct or incorrect?

Comment: @thanks_in_advance notice that I didn't put the drive letter part in the second one. `file:///` is the UNIX form of absolute paths. read through the second link I gave and you'll understand why I used and suggest you to use a UNIX path on windows.