# Is it possbile to use full paths to embed media in Markdown and have them previewed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am trying to set up a workflow where my Markdown documents are code-workspace independent and editor independent. Meaning I can edit and read them in any Markdown editor; Vscode, [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/), [Typora](https://typora.io/) etc. To achieve this I need to use full paths for embedding media. Except for VsCode, all other editors allow the use of a full path for embedding media:

```
![](c:/temp/dog.png)
<img src="c:/temp/dog.png">
```

But VsCode refuses the above style of media linking, all links have to be relative to either the workspace folder or the document itself.

```
![](dog.png)
<img src="dog.png">
```

I am trying to avoid relative paths at all cost. Its a never ending headache, just in code:

- If the Markdown document is not in one of the multi-root folders, its media will not be shown in the Markdown preview
- If the document is in one of the multi-root folders but its media file is not, its media will not be shown in the Markdown preview

And so on... and this is before I even get to other editors and online platforms. It makes the documents I write entirely reliant on VsCode Workspace folder structures. and other editors cannot render them due to the relative paths. I would like to write stand alone markdown files that can be viewed/edited in VsCode just as I can in Obsidian or Typora.

it seems, Microsoft is very sensitive with media preview in markdown, their [explorer Markdown viewer](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/1837) suffers from this same issue. Their seems to be a choice in disabling this security measure in Code, but setting `Markdown: Change Security Preview Settings` to `Disable` does nothing.  Full paths still don't render.

In Code, is it even possible to use full file paths to embed media files? Either the markdown or HTML format, I dont mind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74287664/11107541 but I'm going to hold off dup-hammering because I can't tell if that other question actually cares about the image showing in the markdown preview or not.

Comment: also related: [`file:///` prefixed local file links don't get rendered as links in VS Code Markdown Preview on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77478149/11107541)