# My list of links skips over several links

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have 12 files that are the months of the year that I refer to. All of them are listed in a directory on the C drive. I have checked spelling, all are docx files, all have data in them and I have checked each. I've checked spelling, spacing, periods, backslashes. Then when I open the links as a web page January - March open fine, skips April as File not found, May opens fine, then skips June and July both do the File not found, then the rest of the year open ok.  I am not seeing where my error is. My html is ok per the W3C validator but...these files above do not open in this web page.  Does anyone have any ideas? Please! Thank You!

```
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/January 2023.docx">January</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/February 2023.docx">February</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/March 2023.docx">March</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/April 2023.docx">April</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/May 2023.docx">May</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/June 2023.docx">June</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/July 2023.docx">July</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/August 2023.docx">August</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/September 2023.docx">September</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/October 2023.docx">October</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/November 2023.docx">November</a></li>
<li><a href="C:/k9trc calendar 2023-4/December 2023.docx">December</a></li
```

Comment: That didn't work either. is "file" supposed to be the name of the file I want to open?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `file:///` protocol if you want to link to local files.

```
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\January%202023.docx">January</a></li>
```

You need `%20` for whitespace also good practice.

Take a look at this answer to a similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/23204666

Edit 1

From the comment I received, I also tested this out myself with this code

```html
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\January%202023.docx">January</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\February%202023.docx">February</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\March%202023.docx">March</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\April%202023.docx">April</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\May%202023.docx">May</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\June%202023.docx">June</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\July%202023.docx">July</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\August%202023.docx">August</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\September%202023.docx">September</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\October%202023.docx">October</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\November%202023.docx">November</a></li>
<li><a href="file:///C:\k9trc%20calendar%202023-4\December%202023.docx">December</a></li>
```

It works out correct on my computer, so you need to check out the spelling of the path/filenames or, you could try to copy my code block above and test on your side.

Comment: Showing how much I know, I changed all of the address to your file:/// C: as described above. It made no difference. I still skip over April , June and July.

Comment: Somehow, it doesn't matter how I write each line, using the file:/// with 2 slashes, or three or forward or backward, April, June and July will not work.

Comment: Take a look at my edit from my answer. I tested this out, and it works on my side.

Comment: Thanks, I went through my code letter by letter, line by line and tried it again ... same thing, April, June and July were file not found. I copied your code... same error. I went back and checked my file storage directory and all of the files are there and opened the way they were supposed to. I am a beginner at this but it makes no sense. to me. that

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. I went back and broke the months of April, May, June, July out of the k9trc 
 calendar 2023-4 directory and put them in a new directory called k9trc halfyear . Same result.

Comment: Interesting note, I am using Windows 10 and writing html in Notepad++ but when I run the code and try to open a file I am in Opera. It does it on its own, I am not telling it to go here or there.

Comment: Okay, I use Windows 10 but Firefox. It downloads the file and I can open it without any problems. It sounds like there is an issue on your computer.

Comment: Ok, I rebooted, uninstalled Opera and Brave, ran anti virus, retyped the lines for the 3 months that won't work, checked that the files I am looking to open are really there, rebooted again and April, June and July are listed as file not found. So, for whatever reason I am not supposed to use these files. Makes no sense. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try another browser? For example, firefox just to confirm or exclude things.

Comment: I have no idea how to change. I just run the program and however it comes up that's where I am. How do I select the browser I want to use?

Comment: I went in and changed the name of the 3 files I was trying to open. Saved them with a name like July1. Made sure my documents are the same and still when I    run the html program I get a file not fond error.

Comment: ... error ...found.....

Comment: Please tell what the error was

Comment: No no no I was correcting my spelling error of "fond" should be found. I said that wrong and did not catch it. Sorry.

Comment: Ok here is where I am and it works. I have the 12 months of the year, 9 of them are saved as docx files and when I open them in my html program they open as downloads. But they all open. The 3 I have driven myself spare over, I out of the blue saved them as pdf files and they all open directly. Why? No idea but they all 12 work now. Thanks